# Where can I get a standalone version of the force.com IDE

Tags: force.com, ide

I had to recently setup force.com IDE for my new laptop and i was facing issues with installing eclipse plugin for juno and kepler versions. Kepler version of eclipse worked but intellisense does not work at all. I would like to get the standalone version of force.com IDE so that i can make it work instead of using eclipse plugins? Could you guys tell me where i can get the force.com ide installer for windows 7?

Comment: buyan, have you gone thru the Release notes section already ? it has all the details you need. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Release_Notes

Comment: I still only see the option for eclipse plugin and i am looking for standalone force.com ide downloader option. They used to have this an executable and now i cannot find it all.

Comment: have you considered using sublimetext/mavensmate? just wanted to suggest that as an option if you weren't aware of it

Answer (score 1):

I had a hunt a while back and I couldn't find the standalone app, my guess is that its been discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

I talked to the salesforce developer support team 10 mins ago. The standalone Force.com IDE was discontinued in version 27/28.

The plugin is still available (as pointed out by Vamsi Krishna): https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Release_Notes